# Trouble exporting Juypter Notebook to Markdown with Latex

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I have Anaconda 2019.03 and MikTex 2.9.
When I write inline Latex formulas in a markdown cell in a Jupyter Notebook and run that call, the Latex expression is translated correctly.
When I save that notebook to a markdown file, the Latex expression breaks down.

I write

```
Let $\alpha=0.9$
```

which appears as in the markdown cell as expected, but when I save the notebook to .md, the Latex translation does not work, and the output is

```
Let $\alpha=0.9$
```